# General Technique of Method of Characteristics for PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm working problem 2.5.1 in Evans PDE book. The equation is $u_{t} + b*Du + cu = 0$ with the initial condition $u(x,o) = g(x)$.

I fix x,t and define. $z(s) = u(x + sb,t + s)$ so $z'(s) = b*Du(x+sb,t + s) + u_{t}(x+sb,t+s)$.

So from the first differential equation, we have $z'(s) + c*z(s) = 0$. The solution to this is $z(s) = e^{-cs}$.

How do I get from this to the general solution? I get how to do it if z(s) is constant, but not otherwise. For that matter, how do I get from an arbitrary z(s) to u(x,t)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you have $z(s)=u(x,t)e^{-c s}$, or $u(x,t)=z(s)e^{cs}$.

For the other side:

$g(y)=u(y,0)=u(y-sb+sb,-s+s)=z(s)$, if we set $x=y-sb$ and $t=-s$. So,

$z(s)=g(y)=g(x-tb)$ and $u(x,t)=g(x-tb)e^{-ct}$.

Answer (score 2):

First, you get $z(s)=Ae^{-cs}$, hence you must obtain first $A$. Put in the definition of $z$, $s=-t$ and therefore

$z(-t)=u(x-bt,0)=g(x-bt)=Ae^{ct}$

that is, $A=g(x-bt)e^{-ct}$, and then $z(s)=u(x+sb,t+s)=g(x-bt)e^{-c(t+s)}$. With $s=0$ we get

$u(x,t)=g(x-bt)e^{-ct}$